# Fazer IFRAME ou EMBED dinamico pegar atributo do link clicado

Tags: javascript

Qual maneira um **IFRAME** ou **EMBED** pode-ser criado dinamicamente com atributo do **HREF** clicado naquele dado momento, abrindo-se o *objeto* com o respectivo *URL* daquele link no qual foi acionado através do clique do mouse.

## Código

```
<body>
 <a href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" onclick="abrir(this.href); return false;">Clique</a>
  <hr>
 <span id="exibir"></span>
</body>

<script language="JavaScript">

function abrir(URL) {
obj = document.createElement("embed");
obj.setAttribute("src","'+URL+'");
obj.style.width = 240+"px";
obj.style.height = 180+"px";
document.getElementById('exibir').appendChild(obj);
}
</script>
```

> Resta fazer o script capturar o setAttribute do `<a href='http://pt.stackoverflow.com'>` passando para o `setAttribute("src","");` indexando-o no `"src",""`.

Alguém têm alguma idéia de como conseguir isto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça assim:

```html
<a href="http://www.bbc.com/news/" onclick="abrir(this);return false;">Clique</a>
<a href="http://www.abola.pt/" onclick="abrir(this);return false;">Clique</a>
<a href="http://www.usatoday.com/" onclick="abrir(this);return false;">Clique</a>

<script>
    function abrir(ele) {
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.src = ele.href;
        iframe.width = 240;
        iframe.height = 180;
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
</script>
```

Ou se quiser estar sempre a substiruir:

```html
<a href="http://www.bbc.com/news/" onclick="abrir(this);return false;">Clique</a>
<a href="http://www.abola.pt/" onclick="abrir(this);return false;">Clique</a>
<a href="http://www.usatoday.com/" onclick="abrir(this);return false;">Clique</a>

<script>
    function abrir(ele) {
        var elem = document.getElementById('dinamic_iframe');
        if(elem !== null) { // remover caso exista
            elem.remove();
        }
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.src = ele.href;
        iframe.id = 'dinamic_iframe';
        iframe.width = 240;
        iframe.height = 180;
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Estava eu dando uma olhada nas perguntas que ja tenho feito aqui SOpt, e **notei que não havia dado o merecido Voto** nesta tua resposta. Perdoe-me pela distração por não ter votado a tempo atrás quando precisei da resposta. Mas enfim, você me respondeu então mereceu. rsrs

Comment: De nada @DiegoHenrique. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Ok! @Miguel. Também trago uma outra alternativa de fazer o `<iframe/>` dinamico carregar o *atributo* `href` do link.
Me ocorreu na linha de pensamento substituir o *atributo* `src` para o *atributo* `name` do `<iframe/>`.  Uma pequena troca e veja o resultado disso aqui:

```js
window.onclick=function() {

document.getElementById('exibir').innerHTML='';

obj = document.createElement("iframe");
obj.setAttribute("name","id");
obj.style.width = 240+"px";
obj.style.height = 180+"px";
document.getElementById('exibir').appendChild(obj);
}
```

```html
<a href="http://bing.com/?cc=br" target="id">bing</a> /
 
<a href="http://br.ask.com" target="id">ask</a> /

<a href="http://br.search.yahoo.com" target="id">yahoo</a> /

<a href="http://google.com.br" target="id">google</a>
<hr>
<span id="exibir"></span>
```

Já para o `<embed/>` criado também dinamicamente, refiz o script por completo para que funcionasse como esperado. Confira:

```js
function abrir(URL) {
document.getElementById("exibir").innerHTML = "<embed src='"+URL+"' type='application/mplayer' nocache='0' showcontrols='false' autostart='1' width='' height=''/>";
}
```

```html
<a href="http://cache28.vuclip.com/53/65/5365756905f3dbd79909b3cce52649a3/ba63207/NiceGuys_5365_w_3.3gp" onclick="abrir(this.href); return false;">clic</a>
<hr>
<span id="exibir"></span>
```

> Observe que, ambos resultados sofrerão alguma modificação relevante o significante.

No demais para mim foi satisfatório, agora espero que esta dúvida ou função ajude mais alguém.

Comment: Aí vai adicionar quantas vezes clicar. Vai estar sempre a adicionar à página